# SQL insert into select with parameter for using with event scheduler

Tags: mysql, events, parameters, insert

Hello 
I would like to make event for my application 
that works by insert new 3 record for 1 userID every midnight 
so the quantity of rows must have

`n x 3` 
n is userIDs

```
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
| userID  | userNAME  | chaID |  chaNAME   | goal |  gender  | row_number  | dummy |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
|      1  | Nanyang   |    1  | blahblah   |    1 |        2 |          1  |     1 |
|      1  | Nanyang   |   21  | something  |    1 |        2 |          2  |     1 |
|      1  | Nanyang   |    2  | anything   |    1 |        2 |          3  |     1 |
|      2  | Julie     |    3  | x          |    2 |        1 |          1  |     2 |
|      2  | Julie     |   12  | y          |    2 |        1 |          2  |     2 |
|      2  | Julie     |   23  | z          |    2 |        1 |          3  |     2 |
|      3  | Kingkong  |    4  | a          |    1 |        2 |          1  |     3 |
|      3  | Kingkong  |    5  | b          |    1 |        2 |          2  |     3 |
|      3  | Kingkong  |    6  | c          |    1 |        2 |          3  |     3 |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

the row_number will be looped until they're <= 3

from my written ..

```
set @num := 0, @type := ‘';
CREATE TABLE random
as 
(
SELECT
*
FROM (
select userID,userNAME, chaID, chaNAME,goal,gender,
      @num := if(@type = userID, @num +1,1) as row_number,
      @type := userID as dummy
  from userchar
  order by userID
) as x where x.row_number <= 3)
```

Anyway I used to try to create table with [Select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)
and it works very well and get the result like i shown. then I need to `insert into` in `event` instead of `create table` 
so i got this code below.. because I can't use `SET @parameter`for insert

```
INSERT INTO random(userID, userNAME, chaID, chaNAME, goal, gender,row_number,dummy,status)
    select *
    from (select userID, userNAME, chaID, chaNAME, goal, gender,
                 (@num := if(@type = userID, @num +1,1)
                ) as row_number,
                userID as dummy,
                @stat as status
           from hb_usercha u cross join
                (select @type = '', @num := 0, @stat := '') params
           order by userID,rand()
          )
    where row_number <= 3;
```

and this is a result what I got

```
    +---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
    | userID  | userNAME  | chaID |  chaNAME   | goal |  gender  | row_number  | dummy |
    +---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+
    |      1  | Nanyang   |    1  | blahblah   |    1 |        2 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |   21  | something  |    1 |        2 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |    2  | anything   |    1 |        2 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |    3  | s          |    2 |        1 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |   12  | o          |    2 |        1 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |   23  | m          |    2 |        1 |          1  |     1 |
    |      1  | Nanyang   |    4  | e          |    1 |        2 |          1  |     1 |
    |      2  | Julie     |    5  | xoxo       |    1 |        2 |          1  |     2 |
    |      2  | Julie     |    6  | xxx        |    1 |        2 |          1  |     2 |
    +---------+-----------+-------+------------+------+----------+-------------+-------+

.
.
.
.
```

It seems `row_number` loop isn't working
And I have no idea what's happening 
Both code are same just changed parameters path 
So It would be very good if someone can explain to me 
Thank you so much

Comment: Do you want to do it for all the users exists in `user_char` table or for some specific users?

Comment: sry for late reply but yes i'm gonna do it for all users in database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it for all users exists in `user_char` table.

Using `Union all` to get 3 records of each user and store the result in temporary table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `event_run_midnight` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2016-02-09 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO
BEGIN   

    drop temporary table if exists temp_users_1;
    create Temporary table temp_users_1
    select users.*,@row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num,userID as dummy 
    from(
            select * from user_char
            union all
            select * from user_char
            union all
            select * from user_char
        ) as users,(select @row_num:=0) as row_number
    order by UserID;

    /*
      Copy temp table data to other temp table as MySQL 
       not allows to use same temp table in single query.
    */

    drop temporary table if exists temp_users_2;
    create Temporary table temp_users_2
    select * from temp_users_1;

    -- final query which returns desired output :
    INSERT INTO random(userID, userNAME, chaID, chaNAME, goal, gender,row_number,dummy)
    Select  usr.userID,
            usr.userNAME,
            usr.chaID,
            usr.chaNAME,
            usr.goal,
            usr.gender,
            usr.row_num-usr_grp.min_row_num+1 as row_number,
            usr.userID as dummy
    from temp_users_1 usr
    inner join (
        Select  userID,
                min(row_num) as min_row_num 
        from temp_users_2 group by userID
    ) usr_grp on usr.UserID=usr_grp.userID
    where usr.row_num-usr_grp.min_row_num+1 <=3; -- Condition to show only 3 records of each users.

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Updates:**

1- Added Event Creation.

2- Assuming you are inserting repetitive user records into table name `random`.

3- This Event will execute daily at 12:00 AM.

**Note:**

1- You may have to change the table names if tables names are different as in answer.

2- Make sure that you have enabled MySQL Event scheduler in Configuration file otherwise event will not run automatically.

Here is the link which help you enabling MySQL event scheduler if not enabled:
http://geeksterminal.com/enable-mysql-event-scheduler-status/1711/

Comment: I thought you have distinct user's in `user_char` table. I am updating the answer to get 3 record of each user.

Comment: >_< It's work btw it has any command to don't let them repeatedly? http://upic.me/show/57842425

Comment: I think you have ran old query.Check updated query which contains where clause( last line ) to get only three record of each user.

Comment: sorry i sent u wrong URL http://upic.me/show/57842562 so this is it now with repeated records how can I do next ?

Comment: Would it too much for asking for? I'm sorry i'm a really newbie and get stuck for a long week T.T

Comment: No worries...Wait I m updating the answer :)

Comment: I would say thank you from the bottom of my heart.. you held my breath <3 T.T

Comment: Welcome Nongkarntt :)